# Enable/add scanning to printer from printer server

Tags: printer, network-printer, windows-server-2012-r2, scanner

I have a **printer** that is installed on a **Windows Server 2012 R2** machine and being **deployed** to the Windows clients.

I would like to be able to scan from it, not having to install it locally which is what I've been doing so far.

When it's installed **locally**, the categories under properties for the printer says "**Multi function printer; Scanner**", but when it's **deployed** from the server, it simply says "**Printer**" and **Windows Fax and Scan** is unable to detect a scanner without having it locally installed.

[image: Left is locally installed printer. Right is deployed from server]

How can I enable/add Scanner as a category to the deployed printer so I don't have to install it locally on every machine?

Comment: If the scanner is USB connected then it can only scan to the PC it's connected to. If it's network connected  then it can scan to either email or PC folders. That needs to be setup on the printer (via its Web interface).

Comment: It's a network printer and I would like several computers to be able to scan to their desktop from it. But can the printer only be configured to scan to a specific computer/network path?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [User Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04316164.pdf) page 55 (page 65 of the PDF), here's how you set up network scanning on the HP LaserJet Pro MFP M225, M226.

1. Type the printer's IP address in the address line of your browser, to access the printer's embedded web page.
2. Click the Scan tab.
3. On the left navigation pane, click the Network Folder Setup link.
4. On the Network Folder Configuration page, click the New button.

   a. In the Network Folder Information section, enter the Display Name and Network Path. If required, enter the network Username and Password.

   b. Optional: To secure the folder from unauthorized access, enter a PIN in the Secure the Folder Access with a PIN section. This PIN will be required every time someone uses the scan to network folder feature.

   c. In the Scan Settings section, adjust the scan settings.

NOTE: The network folder must be shared for this feature to work. It can be shared for only you or for other users.

Review all the information, then click Save and Test to save the information and test the connection, or Save Only to save the information only.